# Как обернуть вызов C shared library в вызов C++ shared library под Linux для вызова из C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c

Есть программа на GNU Assembler, возвращающая значение (asm.s):

```
.text
   .globl _new

   _new:               
   mov $1, %rax
   ret
```

Есть библиотечная функция C, вызывающая этот код (my.c):

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
EXPORT int foo(void);
int foo(void)
{
    extern int _new();
    return _new();
}
```

Всё вместе собирается командой в shared library lib.so:

> gcc -shared -fpic -o lib.so my.c asm.s

Пробую через PInvoke в C# .NET Core вызвать:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program{
[DllImport("lib.so")] public static extern int foocpp ();
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int code = foocpp();
System.Console.WriteLine(code);
}
}
```

После

> dotnet run

получаю сообщение

> Hosting components are already initialized. Re-initialization to
> execute an app is not allowed.

Ошибка не ясна, поэтому требуется сделать обёртку на С++ для lib.so, которую уже вызывать через DllImport в C#.

Как будет выглядеть программа на C++, и как изменятся команды сборки на gcc, g++?

Предполагаю, что код будет выглядеть так (my.cpp), но есть затруднение с написанием команды сборки C++ shared library:

```
 extern "C" {
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))        
        EXPORT int foocpp(void)
        {
            extern int foo();
            return foo();
        }
}
```

И пробую собрать так:

> g++ -shared -fpic -o lib.so my.cpp my.c asm.s

Получаю ошибку:

> symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связка C# - Си в вашем коде прекрасно работает, и сообщение об ошибке это только подтверждает.

Проблема вашего кода в том, что `_start` - это популярное имя для системной точки входа (ENTRY POINT) в программу. Эта функция находится в стандартной библиотеке языка Си, и когда вы вызываете её - вы как бы пытаетесь запустить свою же программу ещё раз. Но рантайм .NET Core это обнаруживает, и не даёт вам уйти в вечную рекурсию с переполнением стека.

Переименуйте вашу функцию на ассемблере и попробуйте настроить связку "Си - Asm" ещё раз.

Comment: переименовал _start в _new, пересобрал, подложил библиотеку, и значение вернулось! Огромное спасибо! Но не могли бы Вы ещё привести пример на будущее, как сделать упомянутую обёртку на С++?

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов так же, как и на Сях, только `extern "C"` добавится.

Comment: добавил код для С++ и команду сборки, которые использую. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, - там ошибка при запуске кода C#

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов что-то я не вижу `extern "C"` у функции `foo`

Comment: Файл my.cpp. В самом начале.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста. Совсем новичок в C/C++. Не понимаю, что нужно сделать.